# How to make a POST call to get data from STAT-XPLOR

Tags: r, post, httr

I am trying to get a data from STAT-XPLORE's API through a POST call.
Based on [the documentation,](https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/online-help/Open-Data-API-Table.html) I have written a body for the POST call:

```
#API Key
   key <- "######"

#Endpoint for Table
   tbl_url <- "https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/table"

#########################
#BODY
#--Recode component
   recodes = list(`str:field:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS:COA_CODE` = list(map = "str:value:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS:COA_CODE:V_C_MASTERGEOG11_COUNTRY_TO_GB:E92000001", total = FALSE))

#--Whole list
   body_list <- list(database = "str:database:UC_Households",
                  measures = "str:count:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS",
                  recodes = recodes,
                  dimensions = c("str:field:UC_Households:V_F_UC_HOUSEHOLDS:COA_CODE",    "str:field:UC_Households:F_UC_HH_DATE:DATE_NAME"))

###############
#POST CALL
   response <- httr::POST(tbl_url, body =body_list, encode = "json", httr::add_headers("APIKey" = key), httr::content_type('application/json'))
```

With the call above, I get error 422.
How can I fix this issue?
I've also tried to turn `body_list` into a JSON format with `toJSON` before passing it into POST call, but this also didn't work.